# JQ Mobile: Calling a function with Multiple Parameters from a Listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

A. I have this piece of JQM code that allows to call a function when the user taps on a listview item.

```
$("#MyList").append($("<li><a onclick='MyFunction()'></a></li>"));
IT  WORKS GREAT!
```

B. If I add a parameter to the function like this

```
$("#MyList").append($("<li><a onclick='MyFunction(" + Param1 + ")'></a></li>"));
IT ALSO WORKS GREAT! 
(Param1 is a JS variable)
```

C. But if I want to add more parameters like this

```
$("#MyList").append($("<li><a onclick='MyFunction(" + Param1 + "," + Param2 + "," + Param3 + ")'></a></li>"));
IT FAILS :(
```

I also tried:

```
$("#MyList").append($("<li><a onclick='MyFunction(Param1 , Param2, Param3)'></a></li>"));
IT FAILS TOO
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: What specifically fails? Do you get javascript errors? What does the function your calling look like?

Answer (score 2):

If your parameters are of string type, they need to be enclosed in single quotes:

so replace your following code:

```
... MyFunction(" + Param1 + "," + Param2 + "," + Param3 + ") ...
```

for this one:

```
... MyFunction(" + Param1 + ",'" + Param2 + "','" + Param3 + "') ...
```

In my example Param1 could be a number type parameter but Param2 and Param3 are string type and so I enclose them in single quotes.